# What is standardization's effect on p values?

Tags: regression, linear, standardization

When you standardize variables (prior to linear regression), is it the case that it will **always** increase the p value of your intercept term close to or to 1?

Or, is it the case that your p value on your intercept term will depend on the particular data set you're using (i.e. that standardization doesn't necessarily direct the p value of your intercept term)?

Comment: Why do you believe the p value for the intercept = 1?

Comment: I agree your mean x and y = 0, but I don't follow that that in turn forces your estimated alpha to be 0.

Comment: I missed the definition of a simple regression you provided; p value would = 1 based on how you defined it. I don't follow your definition of a simple regression model, why didn't you use xi and yi (and use x mean and y mean)?

Comment: Makes sense. Given that you standardize BOTH explained and explanatory variables, your intercept = 0 and therefore your p-value = 1. Thanks!

Comment: I will delete my comments because I summarized them in Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose "standardize" means $(X−\bar X)/SD(X)$ for all covariates and response variable. Then means of all covariates and response variable are 0. The intercept $\alpha$ is estimated by
$$\hat \alpha = \bar y -\hat \beta_1\bar x_1-\hat \beta_2\bar x_2-...-\hat \beta_k\bar x_k$$
Therefore after standardization, we have $\hat \alpha = 0$. t-statistics for testing the null hypothesis $H_o: \alpha = 0$ is zero ($t = \hat \alpha/SE(\hat\alpha)$). Obviously p-value for null hypothesis that intercept $\alpha = 0 $ is 1 because $t=0$.